# What is the difference between Mage::getSingleton() and Mage::getModel() in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, singleton, object, design-patterns

`Mage::getSingleton()` always finds for an existing object if not then create that a new object but `Mage::getModel()` always creates a new object.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756753/magento-getsingleton-vs-getmodel-issue

Answer (score 2):

**`Mage::getSingleton()`** will first check the same class instance is exists or not in memory. If the instance is created then it will return the same object from memory.

**`Mage::getModel()`** will create a new instance of an object each time even such object exists in configuration.

Comment: I don't think "So Mage::getSingleton() faster then Mage::getModel()". It's only faster for the second call. For the first one it is theoretically slower because there is an extra `if` involved.

Comment: I don't think the goal of the singleton design pattern is about speed... It is about the principle of having only 1 instance of a certain object throughout the request, implemented for different reasons.